# Loop in Express Server with ioredis: Unhandled 'ECONNRESET' Error and MaxRetriesPerRequestError

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

What can cause this kind of error?

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
```

When I launch a Request the responses is okay but after some request my server `shutDown` with that error.

```js
[ERROR] 14:18:43 MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.
```

Is the error from this code?

`server\utils\redis.ts`

```js
import { Redis } from "ioredis";

require("dotenv").config();
const redisClient = () => {
  if (process.env.REDIS_URL) {
    console.log(`Redis connected`);
    return process.env.REDIS_URL;
  }
  throw new Error("Redis connection failed");
};

export const redis = new Redis(redisClient());
```

You can check all my code [on this GitHub link](https://github.com/wilonweb/LMS-Mern-v1.git).